# Sibling text file string to blob in JavaScript - unavailable?

Tags: javascript

I have a text file (here `big_buck_bunny_trailer_480p.srt`), "sibling" to a html page (so when I run the html page locally, it is a local file - when I run it on server, it is a remote file) - the directory structure is:

```
.
├── big_buck_bunny_trailer_480p.srt
└── ttt.html
```

I'm trying to read the text file using `XMLHttpRequest`; that succeeds fine, and I can get the string content of the text file. But when I try to create a Blob out of it, in Firefox 60 console I get "unavailable".

This is my test file, `ttt.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
  var myblob = new Blob([this.responseText], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  console.log(myblob);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // "To read files that are siblings of the HTML document, use XMLHttpRequest"
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "big_buck_bunny_trailer_480p.srt");
oReq.send();

</script>
```

When I run it in Firefox 60, console prints out:

```
1                                     ttt.html:4:3 
00:00:00,005 --> 00:00:03,800
The peach open movie project presents
(...)

<unavailable>                         ttt.html:8:3 

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. ...

XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: file:///tmp/test/big_buck_bunny_trailer_480p.srt
Line Number 1, Column 1: big_buck_bunny_trailer_480p.srt:1:1
```

So, I get the string right - but why is the Blob `<unavailable>`? How can I get a Blob out of this string?

Bonus question: I get why the warning "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared" appears, - after all, I don't even have `<html>` in my html file. BUt why does `XML Parsing Error: syntax error` appear? All I asked for was to read this file, not parse it? If the parsing is automatic, can I prevent it somehow - all I need are the string contents?

---

EDIT: reduced the example to this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var myblob = new Blob([window.btoa("Hello world")], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  console.log(myblob);

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

... and accessed it by using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, so via `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ttt.html`; and the only printout I get in the console is:

```
<unavailable> ttt.html:22:3
```

So, how do I get an actual blob from a string?

Answer (score 1):

your `html tags` may `interrupt` the `xml parsing`. That's why its throwing `Syntax Error.` That kind of error is very common in `JSON` or `XML parsing`. Before create Blob, encode the `Response Data`.

Try this,

```
new Blob([window.btoa(this.responseText)], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
```

And also, When you retrieve the data from `Blob`. You need to decode using `window.atob()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that browsers won't allow to happen over the `file://` protocol. This is probably one of them.

Instead of running it over the `file://` protocol, it is better to use a small local server to run it over. There are lots of them out there, so lots of options. Many IDEs even have them built in. I like to write a quick 10-line version with Express and Node. Whichever you chose, it'll just serve up static files for you over the `http://` protocol so you can avoid these issues.

Comment: Thanks @samanime - but I thought, if I'm using XMLHttpRequest, then I'm not using `file://`? Or is `file://` implicit, if I run this script/html locally (and if I had this ran from a server, the XMLHttpRequest would interpret `"big_buck_bunny_trailer_480p.srt"` as a `http://`?) That is what I don't quite get...

Comment: You're still using `file://`. In order to use the `http://` protocol, you have to have something capable of communicating over `http://` running locally. If you look in the Network tab of the developer tools in the browser, you can see the full path of the file, which would be `file://`. Protocols require both ends (in this case, your browser and your computer) to understand them. Your computer can't without a server. Since it is relative, it'll always match the protocol of the web page.

Comment: Thanks @samanime - now it made sense; after all, when I open `ttt.html` locally in Firefox, the address bar shows `file:///tmp/test/ttt.html` after all - and its even in the error message there.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried accessing via local server - and I still get 'unavailable' - see edit...

Answer (score 0):

Got it, finally - turns out, if you watch `console.log(myblob);` in Firefox 60 **Browser** Console (Ctrl-Shift-J, the one in standalone window), then you get `<unavailable>`; but if at the same time, you observe the **Web** Console (Ctrl-Shift-K, sits in a tab near the Inspector of Inspect Element right-click), *then* you get a proper printout; see .gif:

[image: test-xhr-blob.gif]

Here it is accessed via a local server, so through `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ttt.html` - but accessing it locally via `file://` protocol yields the exact same results (the blob can be seen in Web console to be instantiated fine, regardless of protocol).

For reference, here is the final `ttt.html` I used while capturing the .gif video:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText.substr(0,60)+"...");
  var myblob = new Blob([window.btoa(this.responseText)], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  console.log(myblob);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // "To read files that are siblings of the HTML document, use XMLHttpRequest"
oReq.overrideMimeType("text/plain");
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "big_buck_bunny_trailer_480p.srt");
oReq.send();

</script>
</head>
</html>
```